# Date field from CSV file doesn't work in c3js timeseries chart

Tags: csv, c3.js

The c3js chart is not displaying properly when I have a date field in a CSV file.
I have set the x axis as type timeseries.
There are only two columns in CSV file. "Date" and "count", e.g.

```
Date,Count
1996-12-20,1
1997-01-31,2
1997-01-31,3
1997-05-07,4
1997-10-03,5
1997-12-02,6
1997-12-02,7
```

---

```
<html>
<link href="http://c3js.org/css/c3-f750e4d4.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"/></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://rawgit.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.js"></script> <!-- This one allows for oninit -->

<div class='chart'>
<div id='chart'></div>
</div>

<head>
    <title>Data from CSV file</title>

<script>
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        x: 'Date', //the x-axis
        x_Format: '%Y-%m-%d', // 'xFormat' can be used as custom format of 'x', default '%Y-%m-%d'
        url: '/dates.csv', //it won't work locally. You need to upload it to a web server
    },
    x: {
        type: 'timeseries', //date format in CSV file needs to be 2000-06-14
    }
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what is displayed:
[image: No dates shown on X axis]

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to add the axis before the x:

```
axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'timeseries', //date format in CSV file needs to be 2000-06-14
    }
}
```

and now it works fine.